# py2exe not working on windows 7 starter netbook

Tags: python, windows, macos, py2exe, parallels

I have a netbook with windows 7 starter and when ever I try to run my setup.py, I get either of these errors with their corresponding changes:
`console = [{"script":"FileName.py"}]`
It won't open.
`windows = [{"script":"FileName.py"}]`
It immediately stops working.

My program has a GUI. It just seems that every setup.py variation I try doesn't work. Any ideas?

Right now it looks like:

```
#### no arguments  
if len(sys.argv) == 1:  
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")  
####creates a standalone .exe file, no zip files
setup( options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1, "optimize": 2, "ascii": 1, "bundle_files": 1}},
       zipfile = None,
       # replace myFile.py with your own code filename here ...
       console = [{"script": 'MyFile.py'}] )
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **setup.py** script worked for me on my **Windows 7 Professional** VM. Tried it with both a simple console script and a wxPython gui script.

It is not in your example (and I'm assuming you have this), but you'd need the following imports in your setup:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup  # or from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
```

Other than that, is your **MyFile.py** in the same directory as your **setup.py**? 
Does your **MyFile.py** run on its own?

Comment: I do have what you included, and yes they are in the same directory. If by "Run on it's own" you mean it doesn't need any other files to run, then yes. Right now I can make the .exe, but it either won't run, or sill immediately stop working, as I said in my question

Comment: I'm giving up on it lol. I'll just be a Mac programmer, as I got py2app to work.

Comment: By "Run on it's own" I meant, does it run with a simple `python MyFile.py`. Seeing as you got it to work with py2app, I take it that it does.

Comment: Py2exe is a bit finicky, especially when it comes to bundling 3rd party libraries - it often fails with libraries that do dynamic imports (because it can't find them during the build) or libraries that share a namespace (e.g. zope.component). There are alot of tricks in the documentation, but it's takes a certain amount of digging. Personally, I've had to do up front imports of 3rd party libraries and even had to repackage zope.component to get py2exe to recognize it during the build. Not much fun.

Comment: Is there somewhere or someone I can send them to, and have them do it for me?